# Do I have to make every object I send through a WCF service a [DataContract]?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, .net-4.0

I am trying to build an Exception Framework for my project. I know (and am comfortable) with marking my service objects as [DataContract]s and passing them back and forth. I have an Exception base class which inherits ISerializable and overwrites the GetObjectData. Can I send that object through a WCF service the same way I can do my DataContracts?

Comment: ISerializable should be fine as long as the field or property is a data member.

Comment: if this is exception-handling specific take a look at [Fault contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx)

Comment: So every object sent through a WCF service has to be a [DataContract]?

Comment: If you sent anything other than a Fault Contract your WCF Channel with enter the Faulted state.

Comment: I'm not following... I can send a DataContract over without entering a Faulted state.

Comment: Specifying and Handling Faults in WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISerializable should be fine as long as the field or property is a data member.